# Google Maps - JSON Markers from VB.Net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, json, google-maps

Currently building a mapping application, reading points from a database.

New to Javascript at this level so a bit lost now.

Creating a Json in VB.Net from SQL data source.

Can anyone help edit my code so as a new map is not created, markers are added to exisiting one? Any edits i've done just don't add points.

VB.Net

```
Dim markers As New List(Of String)
Dim nearbyLocations = CType(sqlData.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
For Each location As DataRowView In nearbyLocations
    markers.Add(String.Format("{{ title: ""Name {0}"", position: new google.maps.LatLng({1}, {2}) }}", location("AccName"), location("Latitude"), location("Longitude")))
Next

Dim locations = "[" & String.Join(",", markers.ToArray()) & "]"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "LoadMap",_
     String.Format("init_map('map', {0}, {1}, 13, {2});", lat, lng, locations), True)
```

Script

```
function init_map(map_canvas_id, lat, lng, zoom, markers) {
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

var options = {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};


map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_canvas_id), options);


if (markers && markers.length > 0) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markers[i]);
        marker.setMap(map);

        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind:

```
Dim markers As New List(Of String)
Dim nearbyLocations = CType(sqlData.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
For Each location As DataRowView In nearbyLocations
    markers.Add(" { ""title"" : """ & location("AccName") & """, ""lat"" : " & location("Latitude") & ", ""long"" : " & location("Longitude") & " } ")
Next

Dim locations = "[" & String.Join(",", markers.ToArray()) & "]"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "LoadMap",_
    String.Format("init_map('map', {0}, {1}, 13, {2});", lat, lng, locations), True)
```

In the aspx page:

```
//<HTML> stuff....
//...
//...

var map;

function init_map(map_canvas_id, lat, lng, zoom, markers) {
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

var options = {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_canvas_id), options);

var positions = [<% Response.Write(String.Join(",", markers.ToArray())) %>];    
var marker;
var curPosition;
for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    curPosition = positions[i];
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(curPosition.lat,curPosition.long),
        title: curPosition.title
    });
}

//..</HTML> stuff
```

Comment: Thanks. How would this be referenced in VB for the script to execute?

Comment: I suppose you have a map drawn already and you wanted to add new markers. How is it you get your "new" list of markers? What I would have done is do a Jquery Ajax call to either a webservice that returns a json.

Comment: New markers retrieved from SQL datasource via VB on button click based on entry fields. No used Jquery before so went for the VB/Javascript route. Idea is user can change paramters and markers will be added based on those.

Comment: Then how can you have multiple maps made? Isn't the map created just once in your code above?

Comment: Yes in this code, however I also have a function executing onload to create a map. I've tried to edit the script/vb to just add to this created map but to no avail.

Comment: Thanks to your help i'm at the stage where I want to reference the Json object created in the VB stage into your javascript.

Comment: You'll have to response.write the Json into the script.